# ruby array of json object access a value

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have an array of json object called line:

```
[{"label":"Name","value":"Bob","identifier":"field2","type":"oneLineText","page":1,"page_name":"Step 1","width":"100%"},{"label":"Email","value":"bob@compagny.com","identifier":"field3","type":"email","page":1,"page_name":"Step 1","width":"100%"},{"label":"Phone Number","value":"","identifier":"field7","type":"oneLineText","page":1,"page_name":"Step 1","width":"100%"},{"label":"Comments","value":"some information about the compagny","identifier":"field5","type":"textarea","page":1,"page_name":"Step 1","width":"100%"}]
```

How do i access the value of label comment :
`"label":"Comments","value":"some information about the compagny"`

Here is my code:

```
data = JSON.parse(line) 
data.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key}"
    puts "#{key} name: #{value["name"]}"
    puts "#{key} value: #{value["value"]}\n"
    label  = value["name"]
    value = value["value"]
    if (label eq "label") && (value eq "Comments")
         puts "#{key} value: #{value["value"]}\n"
    end
end
```

I got an error after first object id parsed:

```
{"label"=>"Name", "value"=>"Bob", "identifier"=>"field2", "type"=>"oneLineText", "page"=>1, "page_name"=>"Step 1", "width"=>"100%"}
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access you data using the following code:

```
data = JSON.parse(line) 
data.each do |d|
  puts "#{d}"
  puts "#{d} label: #{d["label"]}"
  puts "#{d} value: #{d["value"]}"
end
```

After parsing the line with `JSON.parse`, your `data` variable will contain an array of hashes. When you iterate over this array , the block variable `d` is assigned to one of these hashes.

So, the first call to `puts` in this example will show the entire hash assigned to the variable `d`, and the second one will show the entire hash followed by the value assigned to the key `label` of that hash.

Similarly, the third line shows how to access the value stored in the `value` key.